# Bad WiFi reception on Asus Zenbook (Works great with Windows 7)

Tags: wireless, windows, asus, signal

My WiFi reception on my Asus Zenbook (model ux31) is very weak compared to when I boot my Windows 7. I use both from the same location, and the reception on other devices (ex: my iPhone) is great.
I'm now using Ubuntu 13.04, but this problem was present on Ubuntu 12.10 as well.

Any known issues and fixes with the WiFi (driver?).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Nope, I'm still experiencing this. Going everywhere with my RJ45 cable and connector in my backpack. Any ideas..?

Comment: no, idea what do to do...

Comment: http://www.linuxplained.com/how-to-fix-atheros-ar9285-ar9287-wireless-problems-in-ubuntu-1104/

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve it either. I'll keep trying, if I find something I'll post here..

Comment: I read they fixed it on the new 3.11 kernel so I upgraded to the 3.11RC but, it didn't solve it...

Comment: Kernel 3.13.0-30-generic here, having issues

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+t for opening terminal then use -

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-disable11n.conf
```

Now the text file opened , in that add the line at the end of the file

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Save it and reboot by-

```
sudo reboot
```

Now check your internet speed on wifi conection, if that did not work have a look at http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

Hope it helped you.

Comment: This means your connection quality will fall by a large factor.